# Awk : single and double quote regex

Tags: shell

How to write regex in awk to find single quote (') and double quote (") for all lines in file. I want to print those lines

Answer (score 5):

Using input.txt as example.

```
cat input.txt
```

result:

```
'hi sushma'
"second line"
third line
'last line'
```

You can search single quote using hexadecimal representation:

```
awk '/\x27/' input.txt
```

result:

```
'hi sushma'
'last line'
```

or search using scape character:

```
awk '/'\''/' input.txt
```

result:

```
'hi sushma'
'last line'
```

Finally, you can use the OR operator within the regex, for searching for both single and double quote:

```
awk '/'\''|\"/' input.txt
```

result:

```
'hi sushma'
"second line"
'last line'
```

Comment: How can I skip first and last lines for the same regex